# How to interact with web-page in background

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there any way, through which my android application can interact with a web page that I provide?
For example: I want to retrieve user information from a web based erp-system. So first user needs to log-in with his/her credentials. After that, the student home page opens up. I want to know, suppose that I have the credentials in simple text.
How can I insert, 'click' certain buttons elements of the web-page, in background, without any user intervention. Also, once the homepage loads up, Is there any way through which I can access data from DOM elements?
Simply, I just want to know, is this even possible? All the user interaction taking place in the background? And if yes, can someone just point me in a right direction? I actually don't know how to 'term' this process.
Thank You.

EDIT:
I found out, that the button has an associative function 'logincheck()'. So, by calling this function, same can be achieved, right? Problem is, how the credentials can be inserted in the labels and how this function can be called?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download the html page on interests and parse it using **regex** to find out info contained in DOM elements.

Or it s possible to automatize also the login by using for example *Python* and the **request** lib to issue HTTP requests and retrieve the pages.

Another option, more graphic oriented is to use JWebUnit lib (for Java) to navigate the pages and login etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of the webpage or if you have access to it's code, look for division IDs for the form fields that you're trying to fill. Then, in your WebView, once the login page loads, you can fill the form using JavaScript -

Assuming that the username form field has an id 'username' and the password field has an id 'password',

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String js = "javascript:" + 
            "document.getElementById('username').value=" + "'" + username + "';" + 
            "document.getElementById('password').value=" + "'" + password + "';" + 
            "document.forms[0].submit();";

webView.loadUrl(js);
```